# tomcat CATALINA_HOME environment variable issue on openshift

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, openshift, opengts

I am having a weird problem on my server. I am tryng to build OpenGTS so I am using ant all
now while building it gives an error.I am using a Tomcat7(jbossews2.0),Mysql5.5 and Ant Cartridge 0.1.when I open a SSH session and I try to run this command "ant all" it shows that

```
BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/openshift/568e35812d52717d1f000122/app-root/runtime/repo/build.xml:66:
/var/lib/openshift/568e35812d52717d1f000122/app-root/runtime/repo/${Env.CATALINA_HOME} does not exit
```

Comment: Does that environment variable exist when you ssh into your gear and use the "env" command?  It is also possible that you can not use the syntax inside of the build.xml file, as it doesn't look like it's getting replaced properly.

Comment: Thanks corey that evironment variable doesn't exit in ssh.what are you saying that I don't use in build.xml file.

Comment: Here is my build.xml file:https://github.com/shafqatali404/OpenGTS_2.6.0/blob/master/build.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set whatever [environment variable](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#custom-variables) on Openshift

```
$ rhc env set <Variable>=<Value> <Variable2>=<Value2> -a App_Name
```

Comment: Thank you very much Joao Goncalves.But Do you know why It was not there automatically?Because $JAVA_HOME and $M2_HOME are already there on openshift.

Comment: @shafqatali No idea, you can try searching on the openshift quickstarts if they are automatically set.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joao Goncalves